# How to check status of Django generated multiple checkbox?

Tags: jquery, django

I would like to know how to use jQuery to save the names of selected options from a Django based multiple checkbox? It seems like I was not be able to select the group of checkbox... Can someone give me suggestions on my code? Thanks!

jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mMhz4/)

HTML code

```
<table class="tab_model">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="id_model_0">Model:</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_model_0">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="model" value="A" id="id_model_0">Model A</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_model_1">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="model" value="B" id="id_model_1">Model B</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_model_2">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="model" value="C" id="id_model_2">Model C</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

jQuery

```
var allVals = [];

$('.submit').click(function () {
    $('input[id^="id_model_"] :checked').each(function () {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(allVals);
});
```

Comment: `$('input[name="model"]')`?

Comment: Figured it out. I think an extra space ` :checked` kills the jQuery...

Comment: @Ariane your approach also works after removing the space. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give those boxes a class, something like `class='the_checkboxes'`
Then use:

```
$(".the_checkboxes:checkbox:checked").each(function()({
    allVals.push($(this).val());
});
```

It will be cleaner (to me, anyway).

Comment: I agree. Since this multiple checkbox is built from Django, I need to add another jQuery statement to add a class. Thanks!

Comment: Well that might not work, then. Since the classes may not be part of the DOM yet. Why can't you add the class from Django? Are you not using a template?

Comment: Yes. I am using a Django template. Of course, I can overwrite the existed template to add a class.